# Python Dictionary frequency

Tags: python, dictionary, frequency

I have a dictionary of dictionary and need to count how many times letter pairs occur in a given string. I got the dictionaries to work, I just am completely stuck on how to make a counter work for this...

Anyway, here is what I got. Any help is appreciated

```
 test = 'how now, brown cow, ok?'

 def make_letter_pairs(text):
     di = {}
     total = len(text)    

     for i in range(len(text)-1):
         ch = text[i]
         ach = text[i+1]
         if ch in ascii_lowercase and ach in ascii_lowercase:
             if ch not in di:
                 row = di.setdefault(ch, {})
                 row.setdefault(ach, 0)

     return di

 make_letter_pairs(test)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at `Counter` in python? https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: I haven't. Is that the only way to do it? Or can it be done by adding onto my for loop?

Comment: how many times letter pairs occur? what would be the correct output for that test string?

Answer (score 0):

[`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the `collections` module is the way to go on this:

**Code:**

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase 

def make_letter_pairs(text):
    return Counter([t for t in [text[i:i+2] for i in range(len(text) - 1)]
                    if t[0] in ascii_lowercase and t[1] in ascii_lowercase])

test = 'how now, brown cow, ok?'
print(make_letter_pairs(test))
```

**Results:**

```
Counter({'ow': 4, 'co': 1, 'no': 1, 'wn': 1, 'ho': 1, 'br': 1, 'ok': 1, 'ro': 1})
```